# Java Sqlite Library Read/Write issue

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, sqlite

I had created an application in java swing using net beans with sqlite as database. It allows him to add/edit/delete entries using GUI interface. But recently he complained that some of the entries he adds does not appear when he lists the entries. For example after adding 10 entries, he reloads the All Entries pages and finds that all the work he had done was wasted since it does not appear. He said that the issue started to appear when the number of entries crossed 3700 items.

The application runs on a windows 7 system. I am wondering whether this is a cache issue. I always commit after executing a query.

Has anyone encountered something like this? I am thinking of setting PRAGMA CACHE to zero. But will it help?

Comment: *"using GUI interface"* If you can reproduce the observed behavior in a command line app. it means this has nothing to do with Swing & the tag should not be added.

Comment: add logging to your program and have a look where the mistake is hidden. probably in your queries or in your database configuration

Comment: No, blindly changing random settings will not help. Neither will forcing us to blindly guess where in your code the error is. Show the code that writes the data.